# (undefined method `receipts_for' for nil:NilClass - MailBoxer Gem Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, mailboxer

I'm using the mailboxer gem to build a messaging system between users for my rails application. For some reason, I'm getting this error:

(undefined method `receipts_for' for nil:NilClass)

Maybe it's because I should define 'receipts_for' somewhere in my controller or in the mailboxer.rb? I tried a few things.. but unfortunately none of them were successful.

This is my routes.rb:

```html
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root   'static_pages#home'
  get    '/help',    to: 'static_pages#help'
  get    '/about',   to: 'static_pages#about'
  get    '/contact', to: 'static_pages#contact'
  get    '/signup',  to: 'users#new'
  get    '/login',   to: 'sessions#new'
  get    'search/index'
  post   '/login',   to: 'sessions#create'
  delete '/logout',  to: 'sessions#destroy'
  resources :users do
    member do
      get :following, :followers
    end
  end
  resources :conversations do
    resources :messages
  end
  resources :account_activations, only: [:edit]
  resources :password_resets,     only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update]
  resources :microposts,          only: [:create, :destroy]
  resources :relationships,       only: [:create, :destroy]
  resources :searches
end
```

This is my conversations controller:

```html
class ConversationsController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @conversation = current_user.mailbox.conversation.find(params[:id])
  end


  def new
    @recipients = User.find(params[:user_id])
  end

  def create
    recipient = User.find(params[:user_id])
    receipt = current_user.send_message(recipient, params[:body])
    redirect_to conversation_path(receipt.conversation)
  end

end
```

This is my messages_controller:

```html
class MessagesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_conversation

  def create
    receipt = current_user.send_message(@conversation, body)
    redirect_to receipt.conversation
  end

  private

  def set_conversation
    @conversation = current_user.mailbox.conversations.find(params[:conversation_id])
  end

end
```

The messaging system I'm building precisely, is a messaging system where the 'current_user' can go to the profile page of any user on the application and message him/her via the profile page. So this means that I'm rendering show.html.erb of the conversation model inside the show.html.erb of my users model. Here is the code of both views:

show.html.erb - Users Model:

```html
<% provide(:title, @user.name) %>
<div class="row">
  <aside class="col-md-4">
    <section>
      <h1>
        <%= gravatar_for @user %>
        <%= @user.name %>
      </h1>
    </section>
    <section class="stats">
      <%= render 'shared/stats' %>
    </section>
      <h6>
        <%= @user.gender %>
      </h6>
    <%= render "conversations/conversation" %>
  </aside>
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <%= render 'follow_form' if logged_in? %>
    <% if @user.microposts.any? %>
      <h3>Microposts (<%= @user.microposts.count %>)</h3>
      <ol class="microposts">
        <%= render @microposts %>
      </ol>
      <%= will_paginate @microposts %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

_conversation.html.erb - show view of the conversations model.

```html
<% @conversation.receipts_for(current_user).each do |receipt| %>
    <div>
        <%= receipt.message.body %>
    </div>
<% end %>


<%= form_tag conversation_messages_path(@conversation), method: post do  %>
    <div>
        <%= text_area_tag :body %>
    </div>

    <%= submit_tag %>
<% end %>
```

So how exactly can I define the 'receipts_for' method for my mailboxer? Or is something else wrong with my code?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: So `GET /users/:id` (i.e. `UsersController#show`) uses that `show.html.erb` view and that view uses the `_conversation.html.erb` partial? But `UsersController#show` doesn't set `@conversation`? BTW, I generally find that using instance variables to tunnel information into partials just leads to pain and suffering, things are easier to understand when you're more explicit about how the data moves around.

Comment: No show.html of Users model renders the show.html of the conversations_controller. That's it. Why do I need to set @conversation to in the UsersController#show?

Comment: @muistooshort tagging u

Comment: The only `receipts_for` call you have is `@conversation.receipts_for` in the partial, the only thing I see that uses that partial is `show.html.erb` for (apparently) your users. The error is telling you that `@conversation` is `nil` in the partial. "show.html of Users model renders the show.html of the conversations_controller" doesn't make sense to me; models don't render anything, controllers do; methods in `ConversationsController` render views from `app/views/conversations/` unless you make special arrangements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’ll piggy-back on what [@mu is too short](https://stackoverflow.com/users/479863/mu-is-too-short) said. It’s important to pay attention to the whole error message.  “undefined method receipts_for for nil:NilClass” is telling you that the receiver of the  `receipts_for` method is nil.  `@conversation.receipts_for(current_user)` looks to be the only place where `receipts_for` is used, so I would start debugging by making sure `@conversation` is assigned the value of an existing ActiveRecord-backed conversation object.

There seems to be too a lot going on, so I don't know how to offer you a quick fix. The value assignment in your `ConversationsController#show` method, `@conversation= current_user.mailbox.conversation.find(params[:id])` looks cumbersome. That suggests to me that you're looking for a `conversation` based on a `mailbox` belonging to the `current_user`, which might be what you want (in which case, you need to have the appropriate [associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) defined in your models).

However, since the chain ends with `conversation.find(params[:id])`, I'm guessing that `current_user.mailbox` is not needed. Alternatively, if your `params` don't actually have a conversation id, then maybe that's what you need to focus on.

The good news is you can probably figure out how to define `@conversation` if you stick [byebug](https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug) (or [binding.pry](https://github.com/pry/pry), depending on what you have installed) at the top of your `show` method and in your view partial:

```
# In the controller:

  def show
    binding.pry
    @conversation = current_user.mailbox.conversation.find(params[:id])
  end


# in the view
<% binding.pry %>
```

Comment: Hi @Ginnie :) Thanks for helping out. I'm gradually trying to understand the problem and the cause for error. But can you elaborate more on what you mean by: "That suggests to me that you're looking for a conversation based a mailbox belonging to the current_user, which might be what you want (in which case, your models need to have the appropriate associations defined)". What associations exactly should I make in the model? And what model exactly? The User model? Or the conversation model? Sorry if I'm not getting this! And thank you for being patient with me . I'm still a newbie in all this!

Comment: After posting my comment, I came across a Go Rails episode, which is implementing the same mailboxer gem. The author has a link to the source code so you can see how they set everything up. They are using the same value assignment that you have, so you can probably ignore my advice about the cumbersome value assignment for this particular problem. 

Episode: https://gorails.com/episodes/in-app-messaging-between-users
Code on GitHub: https://github.com/gorails-screencasts/gorails-episode-105/blob/master/app/models/user.rb

Comment: If you are new to Rails, I would spend time understanding how to set up has_many and belongs_to associations and look at what methods you get when you have those associations set up properly.